# Making specific text disappearing after it is hit

Tags: lua, coronasdk

The code below removes a balloon when a bullet hits it. I'm stuck on how to make the **specific** balloonTexts disappear when they are hit by the bullet. For example, I wanted to make the balloon that has 'balloonText2' disappear when the bullet hits it. How do I detect its the second balloon i hit?

```
function createBalloons(a, b)
  for i = 1, a do
     for j = 1, b do

         local balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 465+ (i * 30), 80 + (j * 50))
         balloonText1 = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+1], 495, 125)
         balloonText2 = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+2], 495, 175)
         balloonText3 = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+3], 495, 225)
         balloonText1:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloonText2:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloonText3:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloon.name = 'balloon'
         physics.addBody(balloon)
         balloon.bodyType = 'static'
         table.insert(balloons, balloon)
         end
    end
    target.text = #balloons
end
--ball collides with balloon
function ballCollision(e)
   if (e.other.name == 'balloon') then
        e.target:removeSelf() 
        e.other:removeSelf()
        audio.play(pop)
        score.text = score.text + 50
        score.anchorX = 0
        score.anchorY = 0
        score.x = 200
        score.y = 50
        target.text = target.text - 1
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the balloonText's.  What I would consider doing is adding the display objects for the text the balloon object:

```
     local balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 465+ (i * 30), 80 + (j * 50))
     balloon.balloonText1 = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+1], 495, 125)
     balloon.balloonText2 = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+2], 495, 175)
     balloon.balloonText3 = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+3], 495, 225)
```

Then in your collision handler:

```
    e.target:removeSelf() 
    e.other.balloonText1:removeSelf()
    e.other.balloonText2:removeSelf()
    e.other.balloonText3:removeSelf()
    e.other:removeSelf()
```

or something like that.

Comment: I ran the code and used print statement, the code ran but the texts did not disappear..

Comment: check if you don't have any active transitions or other references to it

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign name property of the text object. Then print e.other.name in collision function and see what's the output. I think e.other is getting nil, that's why it's not removing from the display group.